# Is it right to use will after time expressions?

Tags: will-would

Is it right to use **will** after some time expressions?

I thought you couldn't use **will** after before, after...

Both sentences below are right but **will** on the second would be wrong. Or is the first one wrong?

1. Before the app will work, you have to set it up on the website.
2. Clean your room before your father gets home.

Answer (score 1):

Often, *before* NP *will* VP means, essentially, *Otherwise*, NP *won’t* VP.   “You must finish your vegetables **before** your mother **will** give you dessert.” In such cases, *before* isn’t entirely temporal, but also a fair bit logical.

Comment: This exactly. "You must finish your vegetables **before** your mother **gives** you dessert" is a wholly temporal link, she will give you dessert regardless.

Comment: No, @the-baby-is-you, not in my idiolect anyway. For me, it carries a strong sense of, “Don’t imagine you’ll get dessert without finishing your vegetables.” It is **not** parallel  to *When you’ve finished your ice cream we can go to the park* where both the activity currently in progress (eating ice cream) and it’s promised successor (going to the park) are desired by the addressee. The first example’s connotation includes “It doesn’t matter how distasteful you find the prospect of completing the precondition (finishing your vegetables), it remains a precondition that we **will** enforce.”